# Is it possible to abort helm install?

Tags: kubernetes, installation, kubernetes-helm

I would like to know if it is possible to abort a `helm install` after I have fired it. I could not find anything in under `helm install --help` or `helm update --help`.

[Info about helm.](https://helm.sh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you can do is abort the command from the command line with control-C or command-C (assuming you ran it manually, if it's from CI then you can presumably abort the job). Then you can do `helm list` to find the new release and `helm delete <release_name> --purge --no-hooks`, since it's an `install` (it [would be trickier if it were an upgrade](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2956)).